# manually set colours of labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a ggplot, including labels above every point of observation. For the points and lines of the chart I manually set colours:

```
ggplot(data = dfpl2,
       aes(x = Jahr, y = Positiv, group = Landtag, col = Landtag))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_line()+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#CC0000", "#0066FF", "#FF0000"))+
  geom_label(data = dfpl2,
             aes(label = Jahr, fill = factor(Landtag)),
             nudge_y=0.25, colour="white", fontface="bold")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Jahr", limits=c(2003,2018)))
```

How can use those manually chosen colours for the labels? When using the fill command, only the standard colours appear.

Comment: Try adding `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC0000", "#0066FF", "#FF0000"))` to your code. If that doesn't work for you, please make your question [**reproducible**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by editing your question with the output of `dput(dfpl2)`, so that others can troubleshoot more accurately.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Your solution did work, thanks!